# Uninstall Caffe from OSX

Tags: caffe

I'm having problems installing caffe on my osx platform and would like to completely uninstall caffe from my computer. I am wonder how I can delete caffe along with all associated files in directories such as '/usr/local/lib'

Comment: How did you install caffe?

Comment: git clone --recursive https://github.com/rbgirshick/fast-rcnn.git

Comment: That's not going to install anything: Did you use Homebrew, Macports, or make install?

Comment: If you used the make install steps in the README, write `make -n install` to do a dummy install and remove all the listed files.

Comment: I've been using make to compile the library

Answer (score 0):

You uninstall Caffe by deleting the entire installation directory.  Note, however, that you're installing much more than Caffe: you're also installing the Python interface and un-maintained graduate work, and depending on Cython.

PyCaffe should uninstall with the inverse operation of install, such as `pip uninstall pycaffe`.

Also, check your environment variables for any added Caffe references; you may need to remove those by hand.

---

Before you do that, you might post the installation difficulties you're having.  Fixing the original installation may be easier.